# Rooted phone, deleted Google apps, what upgrade options do I have?

Tags: rooting, updates

Just wanted to know what options I have for updating/upgrading my Android OS, now that I have rooted it and deleted all the Google apps from the device?

It's about time it had an upgrade, but now that I've severed it from Google, is doing a factory reset the only alternative for me, should I want to upgrade the software?

Is there a way to make an image of my current install, should the factory reset fail?

Is there some alternative Android project available for users wishing to use Android without Google?

Grateful for any helpful and constructive advice.

Thanks

........................

Samsung GT-S7560 - Android 4.0.4

Comment: First, a factory-reset won't undo your changes: apps you've deleted will stay deleted. Second: The `updates` tag was a good choice, you might wish to check [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/updates/info) ;) Third, in short: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) (and our [rom tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info)) are good starters for your question. As for the image: See our [nandroid tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info).

Comment: Next: Almost no custom ROM comes with GApps integrated. So if you e.g. install CyanogenMod, there won't be any Google Apps installed. For alternatives to them, see e.g. [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/62581/16575) and my article series on [Android without Google](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-1). Last hint:

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will research them for sure. Regarding question & answer format, I'll bear that in mind next time. Thanks :)